# JavaScript Ascending Number Sort With an Exception

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following array defined in JavaScript,

```
var myPriceList = [0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 3]
```

I need to sort the numbers in an ascending order AND so that 0s show at the end of the sort, like so -

```
var myPriceList = [1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

I understand I can write a custom function like the one below but I'm just not sure how to incorporate the exception for "0".

```
function sortNumber(a,b)
{
  return b - a;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function numSort(a,b){
    if(a == 0)
        return 1;
    if(b == 0)
        return -1;
    return a - b;
}
```

If `numSort(a,b)` returns a value `>0`, then the index of `a` should be higher (and thus later in the sequence). If the value is `<0`, then `b` should be later in the sequence. `0` means both are equal in terms or order.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LYuQP/). See also [MDN sort reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description).

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortNumber(a,b)
{
  if(a == 0) return 1;
  if(b == 0) return -1;
    return b - a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 3];
a.sort();
while(a[0] == 0) a.push(a.shift());

// a is now [1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: That doesn't work with `a = [0, 1, 2, 11]`, as it'll end up with `a =  [1, 11, 2, 0]`, as arrays are sorted based upon ToString(a[i]).

Comment: Ah.. thats right. That didn't come to my mind at the time.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 3];
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a*b==0? 1:a-b});
```

/*  returned value: (Array)
1,3,5,0,0,0
*/

Answer (score 0):

```
const sortElement = (num) =>{
return  num.sort((a,b)=>a ==0? 1:b==0?-1:a-b)
}
```